# Dismissing UIAlertController automatically

Tags: iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

My application has a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, which display an alert with `UIAlertController` when the user touches two elements on the screen. Currently, the user must press the OK button in order to dismiss the alert, however I would like to dismiss the alert after 0.5 seconds automatically, so the user doesn't compromise his interaction with the app.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the automatic dismiss of alert view by using dispatch_after of GCD.

Try below code :

```
    let delay = 0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.dismissPopover()
    }
```

Here, `dismissCategoryPopover()` is a custom method that will be called automatically after 0.5 seconds to dismiss the alert view.

Comment: Thenk youu very much @Abhishek, I used your code, but insted of a method like dismissPopover() I used (alert is my UIALertController): alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: Abhishek, Since I'm using Int64 and NSEC_PER_SEC I see this Issue when compiling for iPhone {4s,5}: "file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)", however the app is running in iPhone {4S,5} Simulator, is there any chance that my app could be rejected by Apple because this error? Thanks!

Comment: What happen if there is an ok button on the alert and that the user clicks it before the dispatch is executed ?

Answer (score 5):

I have a custom function updated for Swift 2.1 which uses a UIAlertController to simulate the **Toast** functionality in Android.

```
func showToast(withMessage message:String) {
    let menu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: message, style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    menu.addAction(cancel)
    self.presentViewController(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let delay = 1.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This shows a complete, working solution for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

Present `UIAlertController` and in completion block, dismiss it after specified time.
By default, any code in completion block runs on a different thread so, get the main thread and dismiss UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        present(alertController, animated: true) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    present(alert, animated: true) {
        sleep(1)
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Using `sleep` is a beginner's mistake. You need to unlearn this. You should *never* use `sleep` like that, it blocks the entire app. Use proper  delay instead.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answers are not appreciated .